# trigger asp:button's click event by clicking another asp:button

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, events

i have two asp:buttons.. say button1 and button2, what i would like to do is fire button2's click event when I click button1.. is there a way to trigger click event on an asp:button through code behind? please help, newbie here.

Comment: Why not put your logic for button2 in a separate method so you can call it from button1 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can put the same event for both buttons, something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Button 1" CommandName="Save" />
<asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="Button 2" CommandName="Cancel" />
```

and in code behind (vb.net):

```
Protected Sub btn_event(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click, btn2.Click

   Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)

   'now you have the button instance on sender object, and you can check the ID property or CommandName property do solve what you want to do!

End Sub
```

C# code:

```
protected void btn_event(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    Button btn = (Button)sender;

    //now you have the button instance on sender object, and you can check the ID property or CommandName property do solve what you want to do!

}
```

If you're using C#, remember to set the event click on asp:button tag.

Comment: thank you sir i got it now working.. i didn't got it at first sorry. newbie here.